# How to change or add location to pictures in new Photos app on OS X?

Tags: macos, photos.app

Since I updated my iPhoto to new Photos App from Apple, I cannot find where to change or add location information to pictures. I had a rich collection of places in my iPhoto.

Comment: I think I know what you are getting at, but please explain what you mean by "manage places". (If it's change the location on a photo, that is not possible in Photos.)

Comment: @tubedogg I mean how to add location/place/coordinates to an image?

Comment: That's not possible in Photos.

Comment: Can I apply location out of the Photos and then add images with location to the Photos?

Comment: I believe that's a feature that will come in El Capitan (the next version of OSX